# Tensorflow to Tensorflow-lite conversion

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to port some code to work on a Raspberry Pi. This code uses Tensorflow, but only for three functions.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

[Instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python) say to simply import:

```
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
```

Are the `preprocess_input`, `img_to_array` and `load_model` functions available in tensorflow-lite? If yes, how can I access them? If no, is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, they are not available.
TFlite in most cases is an instrument optimized to run [inference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide) on trained models on various HW.
In case you want to run TensorFlow and/or Keras on RaspberryPi consider [build](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi) it (or use [prebuild](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location)) and use as you do on work station.